# html5shiv conflicting with jquery lightbox?

Tags: jquery, html, lightbox, html5shiv

I was hoping someone could help me before I loose my marbles.....I have a site in html5 and have included the html5shiv, however - in IE8 - when I do this it conflicts with the lightbox and the images dont show. 
Thanks.

here is my

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<!-- META DATA -->
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<meta name="keywords" content="....." />
<meta name="description" content="....." />


<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Neucha' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/main.css"/>
<link href="styles/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="dist/html5shiv.js">

</script>
<![endif]-->

<script src="scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/lightbox.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="scripts/backarrow.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/smoothscroll.js"></script>

<title>.......</title>
</head>
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the problem is html5shiv - the problem is that you're including two separate copies of jQuery.... v 1.7.1, and then two lines further down you include v1.4.3.

These two jQuery versions will *definitely* clash with each other, and will almost certainly break your site, but it could easily work differently between browsers, and would the exact effect you see will depend on which one was loaded first.

If html5shiv is having an effect, will be because it's being included immediately before the two jquery versions. This will tie up the browser and your server for a moment while it loads, which could result in it affecting the order the the two copies of jquery load. (this is particularly likely because the two jQuery copies are coming from different sources)

Solution: Remove the jQuery 1.4.3 line entirely, and just stick with the newer version of jQuery. (while you're at it, this might be an opportunity for you also to upgrade the other jQuery include to 1.8 or 1.9)